# How to deploy a php web app behind firewall?

Tags: php, windows, deployment, firewall

Does anyone know a solution for deploying a PHP webapp behind a firewall on mainly Windows servers? We have 100+ customers who host our webapp on premise, and we would like to setup a deployer, as a part of our bitbucket pipeline, so our code gets deployed on all installations.

1 customer = 1 installation aka deployment

Today we use a small PHP script, and some version control software, to pull code changes once every day. It runs on both Linux and Windows servers.

Hit me with any solutions :)

Comment: This sounds suspiciously like a request for an off-site recommendation for software, a library or similar ... which is specifically off-topic for SO I'm afraid.

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of [PHPDeployer](https://deployer.org/).

You can setup SSH-access on the servers and then configure the script to deploy to the desired IP of the server.